# RegEx rules to force start of string and allow intranet links

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I need a RegEx used in JavaScript to match some URL rules:

- Should start with `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ftps` or `mailto:` (required)
- `www` is optional
- `a-z`, `A-Z`, `0-9` and some special characters `.:-/` are allowed

Since I'm not that familiar with RegEx I tried to use this one found in an answer (second answer @foufos): [What is a good regular expression to match a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/17773849#17773849)

```
/^(https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9/]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9/]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9/]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,})
```

Now this RegEx matches all links I need except two:
e.g. `http://intranet/index.html`
`mailto:sample@sample.com`

So I tried to modify it and added the `mailto:` rule:

```
/^((http(s)?)|(ftp(s)?):\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+[a-zA-Z0-9]\.[^\s]{2,}|https?:\/\/(?:www\.|(?!www))[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|www\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[^\s]{2,}|(mailto:){1}([\w\.]+)\@{1}[\w]+\.[\w]{2,})\s$/gm;
```

At the moment, two things are not working:

- This `url` matches: `www.google.com`, but it should not, since it has to start with `http`, `https`, `ftp`, `ftps` or `mailto:` (required). I just putted the `?` after the `(s)`, so only this should be optional. Why does this not work?
- This `url` still does not match: `http://intranet/index.html` but I thought, I have the right rule for special chars `.:-/`.

TESTING: List of `URL` which should match:

- `https://www.sample.com`
- `https://www.sample-sample.com`
- `http://www.sample.com`
- `http://www.sample-sample.com`
- `https://sample-sample.com`
- `http://sample-sample.com`
- `ftps://sample-sample.com`,
- `ftp://sample-sample.com`
- `ftps://sample.sample.com:3000`
- `ftp://sample.sample.com:3000`
- `http://intranet/index.html`
- `mailto:sample@sample.com`

List of `URL` should not match:
- `www.google.com`

Any inputs?

Comment: Why I got downvoted on this one? I explained what I tried: To force the start of the string, I just puttet the `?` for the `s` in `https` and `ftps` so just the `s` should be optional but one of the others (http, ftp) are required and it does not work since `www.google.com` is still matching? Can't figure out why I got this downvote over here...

Comment: could you provide a list of a few urls that need to match so we can copy and paste it for testing purposes. Also, do you need to check the VALIDITY of the email? as in - if it's a valid email string?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest Regexp:

```
^(((https?|ftps?):\/\/)|(mailto:))[a-zA-Z0-9\.:\/@-]*$
```

You can play with it here https://regex101.com/r/F1SqQo/1

It doesn't check if the URL follows all the rules nor the email address validity.

Comment: sorry for downvoting but this does not validate against what the user asked for - for one, you have combined http and https. The match will also be cluttered with hundreds of matched groups, which the user did not ask for.

Comment: What do you mean "combined http and https"? Also not sure about hundreds of matching groups...

Comment: the way you use the `|` symbol - it's valid for the 2 groups surrounding it - so it means - `s` or `f`. You should have wrapped https / ftps in groups and then untrack the groups with `?:`. Just paste your regex in regex 101 and see that it doesn't match the provided examples.

Comment: Yeah, it had some minor errors (not escaped slashes) - it matches all the sample URLs

Answer (score 0):

This regex matches your strings but DOES NOT valdiate them. This means - it still includes all forbiden characters - like comas. The email doesn't have to have @ - it just looks for non-whitespace characters till the end of each line:

```
(?:(?:(?:(?:http(?:s)?)|(?:ftp(?:s)?)):\/\/)|(?:mailto:))[^\s]*
```